# Pop-up window for Powershell that shows in front of other windows

Tags: powershell, input, interrupt, prompt, foreground

For a script I'm working on, some time in the middle of the script running I want to prompt the user for just a username. The issue I'm having is if the user goes to work on something else I want a pop-up box to interrupt what they're doing and prompt for text input (kinda like get-credential does, but I don't want it to look like a credentials window). Is there any pop-up window command that shows on top of other windows, other than get-credential?

I've already tested VB InputBox, but can't get that to show in the foreground.

Comment: This question might help: [Simple InputBox Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30534273/simple-inputbox-function)

Comment: @techguy1029 Thanks for the link, but I already tried the InputBox answer from that question. It doesn't interrupt the user like get-credential does, which is what I need.